# How to allow users to select when to be reminded based on form input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

To be clear, I'm not asking about delayed jobs or workers or sidekiq.
I have a form where users specify the date of an event, I would like them to also have the ability to specify how many days before that event they would like to be reminded. I'm using the j query ui datepicker on a text field and the date outputs in (dd/mm/yyyy) format. how would I write the code for checking the date they specified and and waiting the specified amount of days before sending the reminder? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what's the problem here. You don't know about `Date.parse`?

Comment: I do, but unsure of what the exact syntax would be in this case. the field name is Due

Comment: Trial and error, mate, trial and error. And books.